# Правильне вживання "олія жожоба" чи "олія жожоби?

Tags: вживання-слів, відмінювання, запозичені-слова

Чи існує встановлене правило для вживання словосполучення "олія жожоба" чи "олія жожоби"?

У Вікіпедіїї зустріла саме "[олія жожоби](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8)". Слово "жожоба" має іншомовне походження (ісп. Jojoba).

Згідно з [правописом](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par100p2) слів іншомовного походження, якщо іменник закінчується на -а з попереднім голосним - слово не відмінюється. А отже, "жожоба" повинно відмінюватися як іменник жіночого роду.

То чому ж так поширено використовують саме "олія жожоба", адже відповідно до правил правопису потрібно вживати "олія жожоби"?

Comment: а чому ви так вважаєте? ви десь перевіряли відмінювання цього слова?

Comment: на цьому сайті заохочується мінімальна самостійна робота. є правопис, наприклад, де можна подивитися правила відмінювання. поки що ставлю мінус. покажете мінімальне дослідження - поставлю плюс, і спільнота постарається відповісти.

Comment: Я трошки розбив на параграфи, щоб було більш читабельно. Перегляньте, будь ласка, там якась нелогічність у третьому параграфі. Ви посилаєтеся на правопис (я додав лінк), який стверджує, що **не** відмінюєтсья. А у наступному реченні пишете «отже, **повинно** відмінюватися». Думаю, там варто відредагувати [edit] і поправити. А то виходить, що запитання суперечить саме собі.

Comment: @bytebuster, правопис каже, що не відміюнюються іменники на _-а_ з попереднім **голосним**. Вікторія припускає, що оскільки попередній — приголосний (_-б-_) і інші критерії з того пункту теж не підходять, то має відмінюватися.

Comment: Чому часто не відміюють — очевидно, бо в російській мові [«жожоба» невідмінюване](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=жожоба). (Що однак не означає, що в українській мові має автоматично відмінюватися. Залежить від того, як сприймати це слово — якщо іменник жіночого, то радше відмінюється, а якщо середнього, то радше ні — аналогічно до [бакара](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1363&page=62), [бра](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=5318&page=199) тощо.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чому часто не відміюють — очевидно, бо [в російській мові слово *жожоба* невідмінюване](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&word=%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0).

Але наведений пункт правопису не означає, що в українській мові це слово має обов'язково відмінюватися, ми маємо невідмінювані слова на -«<приголосний>+*а*»: *антраша́*, *бакара́*, *бра*, *па* тощо — у ньому (пункті) явно не вистачає примітки «зазвичай».

Мені особисто здається, що немає сенсу робити в українській мові ще одне невідмінюване слово. Слово *жожоба* цілком природньо сприймається як іменник жіночого роду, в той час як наведені вище приклади всі стосуються слів середнього.

Практика не усталилася (наприклад: «включаючи олію жожоби» у [постанові № 602](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/602-96-%D0%BF) і «включаючи олію жожоба» у [постанові № 1378](http://zakon2.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/en/1378-96-%D0%BF)). Хоча в [цьому обговоренні у Вікіпедії](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8_%E2%86%92_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0) користувач  Maksym Ye. показує, що практика «олія жожоба» наразі переважає.